# Creating a globally accessible subcircuit/signal (Logisim)

Tags: java, vhdl

I am implementing a single cycle processor on Logisim, which mainly has 5 subcircuits (all intricately designed to be used in the main circuit). These 5 subcircuits will have intricate links amongst each other in the main circuit. In the 3rd subcircuit I am using a RAM, which will basically signify my register file that I access. This register file is also accessed/edited in various other stages. I want to know if there is any way, such that when one of the stages changes a value in the RAM (register file), it gets changed in all the subcircuits (and in the main circuit). I want my register file to act as a universal RAM so that it is a single entity in the whole circuit.

I tried using the symbol of the subcircuit and providing the various inputs and outputs, but if the input changed the RAM in that subcircuit, it doesn't change in the other subciruits.

Comment: Logisim tutorials state "Logisim will maintain different state information for all subcircuits appearing in a circuit. For example, if a circuit contains a flip-flop, and that circuit is used as a subcircuit several times, then each subcircuit's flip-flop will have its own value when simulating the larger circuit." I want to know if there is any way around it. If all the flip-flops can have the same value.

Comment: Pull that circuit out and add it to the top level design. Connect all its users up to it explicitly. I can't help with the details but that is the essence of what you have to do.

Comment: So there is no other way? If I pull it out, my top level design circuit will become a lot more congested, so I wanted another way. Thanks anyway...

Comment: I don't think there is. I am happy to be corrected. But here's how I look at it: You want a change in one place to be visible in another. That implies a connection between them (excluding magic) So make that connection explicit. (Anything else is obscuring design intent,even if the tools permit it!) Since you mention VHDL, I recommend you use its high level datatypes, like records, to simplify the connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a feature in VHDL that provides something similar to what you ask. But before we go into that, you should probably listen to Brian and make your register file a proper entity in your design. This will force you to think exactly how the parts will interact, which you'll have to do at some point.

The feature I'm talking about is global signals. They can be declared in packages and used accross various entities. To be fair, I don't think it would be a good idea. This probably won't make your design clearer, as you expect; it will make it more misterious. Anyway, you're free to try it and then tell us your conclusions.

Here's a small example to show what I mean. It's not supposed to do anything useful, but it runs ok in ModelSim and synthesizes ok in Quartus 12.1:

```
package register_file_pkg is
    type register_file_type is array (0 to 31) of integer range 0 to 255;
    signal register_file: register_file_type;
    alias pc is register_file(31);
end;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
use work.register_file_pkg.all;

entity alu is
    port (
        clock: in bit;
        zero_flag: out boolean;
        last_pc_flag: out boolean
    );
end;

architecture rtl of alu is
begin
    zero_flag <= (register_file(0) = 0);
    last_pc_flag <= (pc = 255);

    process (clock) begin
        if clock'event and clock = '1' then
            register_file(0) <= pc / 4;
        end if;
    end process;
end;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_bit.all;
use work.register_file_pkg.all;

entity cpu is
    port (
        clock: in bit;
        address_bus: out integer;
        zero_flag: out boolean;
        last_pc_flag: out boolean
    );
end;

architecture rtl of cpu is
begin
    address_bus <= pc;

    process (clock) begin
        if clock'event and clock = '1' then
            pc <= pc + 1;
        end if;
    end process;

    cpu_alu: entity work.alu
        port map(
            clock => clock,
            zero_flag => zero_flag,
            last_pc_flag => last_pc_flag
        );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Rick : I had forgotten about shared variables and global signals (are global signals a VHDL-2008 thing?) so I stand corrected. As to whether it's a good idea... I stand by my last comment :-)

Comment: This paper http://www.eda.org/VIUF_proc/Fall96/MCKINNEY96A.PDF describes using global signals in exactly this way. The author does NOT recommend using them in code designed for synthesis! Synthesis tools have undoubtedly improved since then, but I still agree with him!

Comment: I made my project using Brian's advice, and giving up on universal signals. Either ways, I couldn't have generated them in Logisim, since I chose to do my project in that (and not VHDL). Plus I needed universal registers and not signals. I will use this method in my next assignment I guess.